# Rails Koala Facebook & Twitter API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I have created a tool that allows me to do automatic social media marketing by posting to Twitter via API.  I would now like to do that same thing and share the extended message/tweet to my personal FB profile as well as the FB page.  I have figured out a way to post to FB using Koala, the only thing is that the token constantly expires.  Is there a way where I can continuously be connected like I am with the Twitter API?

Any thoughts, ideas, or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249778/facebook-token-expiration-and-renewal-with-koala-and-omniauth-facebook

Comment: I dont have "users" , this is just for my own purposes.  This is essentially just hosted code online with no portal for login/logout.

Comment: I was looking at the first answer, "What I have is a before_filter that.....". That doesn't use users, it just resets the token if it has expired.

Comment: ahh ill go take another look

Comment: yea im not sure about that, I dont have omni-auth and would prefer not to have to install that JUST to store one token. Maybe I am over thinking this? I'm still pretty new to rails

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a long-lived access tokens:

> User access tokens come in two forms: short-lived tokens and
>   long-lived tokens. Short-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about
>   an hour or two, while long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of
>   about 60 days.

As you can see, even user's long-lived token will expire eventually. So it's up to you to either build a small tool to notify you when a token is about to expire or not. But in all cases, this can be done with cURL pretty easily (I have no ruby-on-rails experience): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

> - Start with a short-lived token generated on a client and ship it back to your server.
> - Use the user token, your app ID and app secret to make the following call from your server to Facebook's servers:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** that page access tokens generated from a long-lived user access tokens will **NOT** expire, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extendingpagetokens

> To get a longer-lived page access token, exchange the User access
>   token for a long-lived one, as above, and then request the Page token.
>   The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time.

Comment: I will give this a shot once I reach my computer